# Non-linear second-order ODE, $y''+y^{-1}(y')^2=y^{-1}e^{-y}y'$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I am not sure what method to use for the following ODE,

$$y''+y^{-1}(y')^2=y^{-1}e^{-y}y'$$

With $v=y'$, I got $$v'+y^{-1}v^2=y^{-1}e^{-y}v$$ and with $w=v^{-1}$,

$$w'+y^{-1}e^{-y}w=y^{-1}$$

Comment: Please avoid math-only titles. These are discouraged for a technical reason - see [Guidelines for good use of MathJax on question titles](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/a/9730).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

$$y''+y^{-1}(y')^2=y^{-1}e^{-y}y'$$
$$yy''+(y')^2=e^{-y}y'$$
You have derivatives on both sides:
$$(y'y)'=-(e^{-y})'$$
Integrate both sides.