# Is it possible to continue solving $(y'y)'=-(e^{-y})'$ with elementary functions?

Tags: integration, ordinary-differential-equations

I was reading [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4212790/non-linear-second-order-ode-yy-1y2-y-1e-yy/4212817#4212817) on Solving ODE $y''+y^{-1}(y')^2=y^{-1}e^{-y}y'$. Which reduced to solving $(y'y)'=-(e^{-y})'$ According to MtGlasser's answer. So here what I've done to continue solving ,

$$y'y=e^{-y}+C_1$$
$$\frac{y\;dy}{e^{-y}+C_1}=dx$$I was trying to evaluate the integral but wasn't successful then checked with [wolfram alpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%5Cint%20%5Cfrac%20%7By%7D%7Be%5E%7B-y%7D%2Bc%7Ddy). According to WA there is no elementary solution to integral. I wonder does that mean we don't have elementary solution for $y''+y^{-1}(y')^2=y^{-1}e^{-y}y'$ Or we can do algebraic manipulation differently to get an answer without functions like $\text{Li}(u)$ ?

Comment: I think there is no possibility to get an elementary solution. Why? You can get close by trying $y=\ln x$. But then you have $\frac{\ln x}{x} = \frac{1}{x}$. Having $y$ in the exponent and on the base line simultanesouly doesn't work quite well...

Comment: If $C_1=0$ there is an elementary integral.